# Python: Error "TypeError: Can't convert int to str implicitly"

Tags: python, syntax-error, typeerror

Having such a frustrating time trying to find the error in this. Very new to Python (first year, 3rd week student at uni).

```
age = int(input("Enter your current age in years: "))
if age >= 100:
    print("You've already turned 100!")
elif age < 0:
    print("Try again after you are born!")
else:
    print("You will be 100 in " + (100 - age) + " years!")
```

This throws an error "TypeError: Can't convert int to str implicitely" if I enter a mid-range value, eg 18. I can't find what's causing the problem here??

Comment: try explicitly type casting. ie.. `str((100 - age))`. Also try reading and figure out what the error message really says. Would help you a lot going forward.

Comment: Python cannot do the implicit conversion of your calculation `100 - age` in the middle of the string concatenation.  Try wrapping the calculation within a string conversion: `str(100 - age)`.  This forces Python to 1) do the calculation, 2) convert the result to a string, and 3) concatenate it to your output.  Also, check out the string.format() method for doing this type of thing, and the newer f-strings.

Comment: That's confusing, I'm not trying to make it a string, but it works if I do it like you've both suggested. How can it calculate it if it's set to type 'String'? I always thought it had to be an integer or float to calculate!

Comment: The calculation does need to be numeric, but once Python has done that, it needs the result to be a string before it can perform the concatenation with your other strings (because strings are immutable).  So you take your numeric result, then you have to convert it (that's what the `str` does).  Now you have a string which you can join to other strings.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Thanks for clearing that up for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because it fails on the first to condition and goes to the `else` block. Then it tries to execute this `print("You will be 100 in " + (100 - age) + " years!")` statement. The statement is trying to print the `age` variable, which is initially an `int` type. However, to print that, the variable has to be of `str` type. Therefore, it is trying to implicitly convert `int` to `str`, which it can't do (hence the error).

To fix that simply use `str()` function, to convert from `int` to `str` explicitly

```
print("You will be 100 in " + str(100 - age) + " years!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your print statement is the culprit here. When you do your subtraction, the result of your operation is a non-string type. In your case, it will always be an int, as you cast your input to integer when you read it (this is where your program will fail if the user inputs non-integers). The print statement tries to join two strings and one integer and it fails, so you get the TypeError.

So your fix is relatively simple: cast the result of your subtraction to string before joining it to the other strings.

```
print("You will be 100 in " + str(100 - age) + " years!")
```

Answer (score -1):

has to do with this line:

```
print("You will be 100 in " + (100 - age) + " years!")
```

change to:

```
print("You will be 100 in {} years!".format((100 - age))
```

format will take care of the conversion to a string for you